# Translucent banner across all the layouts in my Vaadin app, à la Vaadin Charts 2 Demo license?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

The new [Vaadin Charts 2](https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts) add-on offers a time-limited trial license.

During that trial period, your app launches with a translucent grey bar at the bottom of the UI (browser window/tab). The grey bar displays a bit of text. The grey bar also reacts to a user’s click (bar disappears). The bar remains in place on the UI even while I change my layouts underneath.

[image: screen shot of Vaadin app’s tables obscured by floating translucent bar]

I would like to provide exactly that same behavior within my own app. When urgent alerts are pending, I want to notify the user with a bar across the screen. I want to react when the user clicks that bar. I want that bar to appear and remain displayed regardless of what layouts are changing beneath the bar.

Rather than have to have every layout manage some urgent-alert notification widget, I want just one widget (translucent bar) to float over the entire rest of the app.

Is there some way to provide that app-wide bar on my own?

To clarify, the more important part of the Question is is not the translucency of the bar. The more important part is: How to float this bar over any and all content in the UI. That Vaadin Charts "Using Evaluation License" remains displayed while underneath I change from a VerticalLayout to a GridLayout to a TabSheet. So, that’s the core of my Question, how to float a bar over the changing Layouts in that UI **without making each Layout aware** of the bar widget.

Comment: I am sure you can do this by extending CssLayout and make use of absolute positioning

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [CssLayout](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/CssLayout.html).

```
public class Bar extends CssLayout
{
    public Bar()
    {
        addStyleName("bar");
        addComponent(new Button("Click"));
    }
}
```

And style it with:

```
.bar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background: blueviolet;
}
```

That produces together with coresponding table:

[image]

Remember to setContent of your UI class to another CssLayout, otherwise your bar will appear next to the table. That's because mostly used VerticalLayout assign equal space for every child component.

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    final CssLayout layout = new CssLayout();
    setContent(layout);
...
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    layout.addComponent(bar);
}
```

You can download full example [here](http://pastebin.com/QbyW10cq).

Comment: That answers the translucent layer. But the more important part of the Question is how to float this bar over any and all content in the UI. That Vaadin Charts "Using Evaluation License" remains displayed while underneath I change from a VerticalLayout to a GridLayout to a TabSheet. So, that’s the core of my Question, how to float a bar over the changing Layouts in that UI without having to make each Layout aware of the bar widget. But thanks for this answer, as I'm sure it will help others.